# Uploading output of ffmpeg to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, live-streaming

I am trying following windows command

`ffmpeg -i <M3u8 Stream> -an -r 2 -t 60 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg pipe:a_%0d.jpg | aws s3 cp - s3://ffmpegbucket-1`/

The objective is read a live stream keep generating frames and as soon I get 1st frame transfer it to AWS S3 bucket. So this will be continous upload process

But this command is not working.

Can you please help?

Comment: Did you try uploading to s3://ffmpegbucket-1/myfile.mpeg?

Comment: But ideally that wont work as ffmpeg is generate multiple files using a_%0d format

Comment: I doubt that approach would work. There is no concept of "piping files". It is expecting the contents of one file that it should copy to an Amazon S3 bucket. You should output the files to disk, then use `aws s3 sync` to copy any files that were created.

Comment: Why use MJPEG with multiple files?  Why not just one stream?

Comment: i need frames to be uploaded on S3. not stream

Answer (score 0):

With the basics of linux,

```
Command1 | Command2
```

does the same as

```
> Command1 > tempfile
> Command2 < tempfile
```

In your case first command,

> ffmpeg -i  -an -r 2 -t 60 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg
>   pipe:a_%0d.jpg

**need to complete** its processing before its works on the next command.

> aws s3 cp - s3://ffmpegbucket-1/

Since your first command never completes and the copying to s3 never started.

Hope it helps.